# ssh alias with localhost forwarding

Tags: ssh, command-line, alias

Does anyone know what the best way is to create an ssh alias with a localhost argument? Everything I've searched for only includes host, hostname, etc. Such as:

```
Host example2
  Hostname example.com
  User exampleuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/another_ssh.identity
```

What I'd like to create is a shortcut in my ~/.ssh/config file with an alias for

```
ssh -L 9999:localhost:8888 user@myserver.com
```

Comment: What's wrong with putting it into a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `LocalForward`, in your case

```
Host example2
    Hostname myserver.com
    User user
    LocalForward 9999 localhost:8888
```

Comment: reference: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5